# Replace String present in double quotes in unix shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have input like below

```
<tag col1 = "" col2 = "" >
<Data>
</tag end>
<tag1 col1 = "" col2 = "" col3 = "" >  Here col1 can have some data(like col1 = "Data can be available") or it cane be empty (like col1 = "")
<data>
</tag1>
<tag2 col1 = "" col2 = "" >
<Data>
</tag2>
```

OutPut like below

```
<tag>
<Data>
</tag>
<tag1 col1 = "Updated Comments" col2 = "" col3 = "" >
<data>
</tag1>
<tag2 col1 = "" col2 = "" >
<Data>
</tag2>
```

I need to update just col1 on tag1 with updated comments and input can be empty or can have some other characters for col1 but I need to replace that col1 alone with updated comments

I tried below but it is now working as expected. If I am trying below one the other values (col2 = "" etc) in the line is getting truncated

```
sed -e 's/tag1 col1 =".*"/col1 =\"Updated Comments\"/' test_file.txt
```

Comment: Aside from the spaces, this looks like XML. If so, use an XML aware tool like `xmlstarlet`, not `sed`.

Comment: yes this is an XML file, but I need to use UNIX shell script and replace, so I am using sed. Kind let me know if any other option is available

Comment: `xmlstarlet` is a command line tool meant to be used in scripts, yes.

Comment: Way nicer than the other usual approach, which is writing a XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: Or whip up a small perl/python/ruby/etc. script to do it using an XML parser library.

Comment: I am not sure how use those commands to achieve above. Can you please help with the code to achieve above

Answer (score 0):

The output is little confusing as it makes it look like all the other xml tags need to be modified.

But your question/ sed command talks only about replacing the tag1 contents. the `.*` in your `sed` pattern match is greedy and will try to match as much as possible. You need to pattern match everything except the `"`.

```
> echo '<tag1 = "current comment" col1 = "">' | sed -e 's/tag1[ ]*=[ ]*"[^"]*"/tag1=\"updated description\"/g'
<tag1="updated description" col1 = "">

> echo '<tag1 = "" col1 = "">' | sed -e 's/tag1[ ]*=[ ]*"[^"]*"/tag1=\"updated description\"/g'
<tag1="updated description" col1 = "">
```

Comment: I just updated with correct columns in tag1. Previously I missed col1. Please check and let me know which one will work now. Thank you

Comment: Hi @SatishVaradha, you can use `sed -e 's/tag1[ ]*=[ ]*"[^"]*"/tag1=\"updated description\"/g'` and let me know if it works.